# Why are images not showing up with Carbon's HTML rendering library

Tags: macos, macos-carbon, html-rendering

I have an old program that shows an embedded browser using the HTML Rendering library from Carbon. I am migrating it from codewarrior to Xcode, using the 10.4 SDK. While the HTML is displayed correctly, including links, the images just don't show up. I can see the alt content, and dimensions are properly set with the width and height fields.

I am doing the initialization with:

```
OSErr err = HRNewReference(m_HRRef, kHRRendererHTML32Type,
            GetWindowPort((WindowRef) m_pWindow));
```

And then I open my local HTML file with:

```
err = HRGoToFSRef(m_HRRef, &f, false, false);
```

My images are also stored locally but just do not appear, it was working fine previously on my ppc-only codewarrior compilation.

I tried with web pages on Internet with HRGoToURL, and I tried replacing my pictures src fields with http:// or file:// links to images, in jpg, gif and png, always with the same result.

Are you aware of any issue like this? I know I could, and probably should, migrate to WebKit but that would me more involved.

Sylvain

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark (I am completely unfamiliar with HTMLRenderingLib), but it reminds me of [this](http://wilshipley.com/blog/2006/07/pimp-my-code-part-11-this-sheet-is.html). Maybe here too it doesn't load images, even local ones, asynchronously; have you tried letting the run loop loop (whichever way is most appropriate to your app: WaitNextEvent, return back to the main runloop, spin a sub event loop, …) and see if the images load?

Comment: Thanks Pierre for your suggestions. I tried to test your suggestions (although I am not sure I did it right), but images never appear. Meanwhile I also tried to embed the images in the HTML using data URI, and also to directly open an image rather than an HTML file. The data URI will also not appear, and if I open an image, the binary content will just be displayed as text. So I am guessing it is not an issue with the asynchronous load of images.